# Overlay ggplot pie chart on a rworldmap plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, overlay, rworldmap

I have created multiple pie charts with legends in `ggplot`. I am also using `rworldmap` to create maps of Eurasia with coordinates plotted as points on the map.

The pie charts I have correspond to the points I have plotted on my maps. My end goal is to overlay the pie charts I have created in `ggplot` on to my `rworldmap` plots, and then display all of the maps in a grid. I would also like to add the legends from my `ggplot` pie charts to the maps.

I have added my pie chart to an object(?) `AD_Pie`, using `AD_Pie <- ggplot(df, aes...) +` etc.

I have created my map using:

```
AD_Map <- getMap(resolution = "low")
plot(AD_Map, xlim = c(-27.0, 174.0), ylim = c(17.5, 75.0), col = "grey",border = "darkgrey", xlab = "", ylab = '' , bg= "lightblue")
points(Coordinate_AD_Clean$long, Coordinate_AD_Clean$lat, col = "red", pch = "+")
```

`Coordinate_AD_Clean` is my data frame.

My question is whether there is a way to overlay `AD_Pie` on to my plot in `rworldmap`. There doesn't need to be any interaction between the two plots, so hypothetically it would be enough to have even an image of the pie chart overlayed on to the map saved as a single plot that I can then add to a grid/matrix of all the completed plots.

There is a `mapPies` function in `rworldmap` and some functionality to add new pie charts to maps using this package, but the pies I have created in `ggplot` have taken significant data formatting and tweaking to get to, so using this function is not really an option.

I am very much hoping that some sort of overlaying function exists in either `ggplot` or `rworldmap` that I can use to put these pieces together. If you can help I would appreciate it greatly. Thanks for reading, and let me know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but solutions may be easier by using the `ggmap` package instead of `rworldmap`.